# Is $this->uri->segment(3) secure in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Can I do Database operation `$this->uri->segment(3)` ? Is that Secure or Do I need to add : `$this-input->get($this->uri->segment(3))` ?

Comment: What do you expect `$this-input->get($this->uri->segment(3))` to do?  That doesn't look quite right.

Comment: User input is ***never*** secure!  If you are doing database operations, you need to use prepared queries!  Or use CodeIgniter's active record/query builder, it'll prepare/escape the values for you.